# X-bar tree for a sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> Those talents, as they make a part of his fortune, so do they likewise of that of the society to which he belongs.  (Adam Smith, *The Wealth of Nations*)

The structure of the sentence above from Adam Smith's *The Wealth of Nations* is too complex for me. I have tried a few times to draw the X-Bar tree but I couldn't.

Is "as they make a part of his fortune" an embedded clause? I would appreciate it if you could draw the tree or explain the structure of the sentence (constituents).

Comment: You should ask this question on our Linguistics site, here [link](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: @BillJ Two problems there, unfortunately. They won't help with syntax trees, and they won't do language-specific questions (although there seems to be some leeway with the latter, occasionally)

Comment: Would it be on topic here at ELU to at least explain what refers to what? The sentence is pretty convoluted.

Comment: @Araucaria That's true. I've put up a few CGEL-type trees there in the past, and no one has complained, though I don't (can't?) do x-bar stuff.

Comment: I think you're on the right lines. The structure of the sentence resembles a correlative comparative one, but here the subordinate clause functions as complement to "as": "As those talents make a part of his fortune, so do they make a fortune of the society to which he belongs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-bar is a general, structural, formal template for phrase structure. Specifically, X-bar assumes that phrases have a head, X° which may take a complement  forming an intermediate category X', which in turn can occur with a specifer to form a maximal phrase, XP.

X-bar is *not* a comprehensive theory of syntactic structure.
Hence, there is no such thing as "the" X-bar tree for your sentence. 
Rather, there are **many possible trees conforming to the X-bar format**, which differ widely in detail depending on your specific syntactic assumptions.
Your sentence is extremely complicated, involving displaced constituents, parentheticals, and ellipsis! Hence, it's unreasonable to expect there to be one, consensus, standard tree for it.

This being said, here is *one possible* syntactic analysis that conforms to the formal principles imposed by X-bar.

[image]

This tree makes a lot structural assumptions, which are not part of X-bar, such as:

- The tree uses a CP-IP-VP hierarchy of projections.
- Pronouns, like *he*, are of category D.
- English has an empty tense agreement morpheme in I in clauses with finite lexical main verbs.
- Any machinery that would explain displacement is omitted (here formalized as movement with a trace, t, *belongs to which* ->  *to whichs ... belongs*).
- *Wh*-relative clauses involve an empty C-head.
- Interrogative pronouns, like *which*, are of category D.
- Relative clauses are adjoined to NP.
- The tree follows the "DP-hypothesis" - structures like *the fortune* are headed by "the", not by "fortune".
- Co-reference in relative clauses is accomplished by simple co-indexing (*society*<sub>j</sub> ... *which*<sub>j</sub>)
- The *of*-phrase after *fortune of* and *part of* is a complement.
- Ellipsis is modelled as deletion, shown with a strike-through. That analysis is used for gapping and noun-ellipsis.
- Specifiers are used exclusively for subject positions.
- *Likewise* is an adverb.
- Adverbs are adjoined to VP.
- There is a correlative relation between the *as*-clause and resumptive *so*, shown by co-indexing
- Left-dislocation with resumptions (in *those talents* ... *they* and *as* ... *so*) is adjunction to CP.
- subject auxiliary inversion is I-to-C movement.
- The possessive *his* is of category D.
- The clause *as they make ...* is a free relative - it means "in that manner in which they make", involving fronting of *as* functioning as an operator.